# Drupal 8 - User Login

Tags: 8, forms, users

I am using Drupal 8 and want to know how I make my wesbite only usable when a user login. At the moment my websites features also used when a user has not logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Admin -> People -> Permissions, and uncheck any permissions for anonymous users.

Go to Admin -> Configure -> People -> Account settings, and under 'Who can register accounts?', choose 'Administrators only'.

Comment: Thank you! Which setting will allow the anonymous user to just be able to view the home page?

Comment: You can try this module, though I don't know if it is usable for Drupal 8: https://www.drupal.org/project/front